# Facebook Graph API with Rails and Authlogic - preferred methodology?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, authlogic, ruby-on-rails-3

There are lots of Facebook + Rails solutions, most notably Facebooker, but this and many others are not compatible with Rails 3. I'm currently using Authlogic for authentication with my app, and I want to give users the option of Facebook to sign in. I want to find the best way to have FB and Authlogic go together; right now I'm just writing my own Authlogic add-on for Facebook but if this has already been done then I don't want to redo someone else's work. Does anyone know of anything like this?

Answer (score 0):

This area seems to be heavily in flux. I had a difficult time getting it set up with Rails 3 since none of the main Ruby facebook libraries are officially updated for it yet, and the newest ones aren't documented.

The way I got it working with Rails 3 was using Facebooker2 and Mogli. I basically took the mogli + authlogic oauth controller code [posted here](http://groups.google.com/group/facebooker/msg/1d96dd19c61e76a8) and combined it with Facebooker2's controller and helper methods. There's no documentation (that I know of) for Facebooker2 and Mogli, but the Facebooker2 code is relatively straightforward.

I also had to manually deal with some of the authlogic validations in order to have them trigger only for non-facebook signups. Here is all the authlogic-specific code in the user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  acts_as_authentic do |config|
    config.validate_email_field = false
  end

  validates_length_of :email, :within => 6..100, :if => :is_not_fb_user?
  validates_format_of :email, :with => Authlogic::Regex.email, :if => :is_not_fb_user?
  validates_uniqueness_of :email, :if => :is_not_fb_user?

  def is_fb_user?
    return false if self.fb_uid.blank? || self.fb_uid == 0 || self.fb_at.blank? 
    return true 
  end
  def is_not_fb_user?; !self.is_fb_user? end

  def require_password?
    if self.is_fb_user?
      false
    else
      new_record? || password_changed? || send(crypted_password_field).blank?
    end
  end
end
```

There might be some bugs and I suspect there is a better way to approach this.

Answer (score 0):

A friend has developed this gem for our application, so maybe it's useful on your app too: http://github.com/pfracarolli/facebook-graph.

Comment: Is there any documentation for this gem available?

Answer (score 0):

Use Omniauth.  There's a railscast on just this subject.  I believe he even uses it in conjunction with Authlogic:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-omniauth-part-1

Just a few lines to your SessionsController, and a few lines in a config file in config/initializers/omniauth.rb and you are more or less done.

Comment: In the introduction it's clearly specified: `In this episode we start integrating it with *Devise*.`